# How do I assign Sublime key mappings for commands in the sidebar context menu?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

When browsing files in the Sublime sidebar, I would like to quickly access the commands available in the context menu via shortcuts. E.g. Delete file, rename file/folder, new file/folder.

(FYI: super+N is *not* an ideal solution for creating new files - it isn't context aware and will usually choose an inappropriate default location).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable command logging by inserting the following into the console `sublime.log_commands(True)`. This will give you the commands and arguments being executed. You can then create a key binding with the appropriate command. My guess is the commands will use some sort of path, so you may need to write a small plugin to inject the correct paths for the various commands.

For new file creation specifically, you may want to take a look at [AdvancedNewFile](https://github.com/skuroda/Sublime-AdvancedNewFile). Disclaimer - I'm the current maintainer of the plugin. I've tried to make it a more flexible than it originally was, with regards to specifying where to create the file. Though if you do decide to use it and have feature request, feel free to create an issue about it.

Comment: It seems bizarre to me that this is not a standard shortcut within a pure text editor like Sublime. Re. creating my own, how do I get the current path of the sidebar? Given that information (and I cant seem to find it on Google), I think I can muddle my way through a custom plugin :)

Comment: As of right now, there is no way (that I know of) to place the cursor somewhere in the side bar, and get the highlighted folder/directory from a plugin. However, you can get the path of the current file you are working on, and a list of directories for the project. See `view.file_name()` and `window.folders()` in the API docs. I personally use a combination of [FuzzyFileNav](https://github.com/facelessuser/FuzzyFileNav) and AdvancedNewFile for my file creation/system navigation needs.

Comment: Does repeating the same path over each time not bother you? Or does AdvancedNewFile autocomplete folders for you? Also this doesn't solve deleting or renaming items, although I will still give it a look :P

Comment: There is some auto completion, so not really :). In addition, you can do things like create aliases or start from the current folder, so depending on where you are creating the files, it's not as big of an issue. They looked pretty straight forward, with regards to creating a key binding for them, or accessing them via another plugin that will generate the path you want.

Comment: Will definitely consider your plugin. However, *if only* I could access the path of the currently selected node in the sidebar, I could write a plugin which solved the original problem. Do you know a way of obtaining this variable?

Comment: It's on the list of things to do if/when there is an API call for it. In fact, there is an issue I have left open for that just as a reminder. But for now, it's not possible. Or perhaps I need to dig around more to find an undocumented API call.